# EJS render and scroll to section

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I want to render my index but scroll down to my form section.

I want to do something like this :

```
app.post('/rsvp', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index/#rsvp', { errors: { email: 'Your email has already registered'}})
}
```

My index.ejs has a section like this:

```
<section id="rsvp">
  <form name="rsvp" id="newRsvp" method="post" action="/rsvp">
    <div class="form-group">
      <% if (locals.errors.email) { %>
         <p>Enter your email</p>
      <% } %>
  </form>
</section>
```

What is the best way to do this with EJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `render` is the **filename** of the template.

It isn't a URL that the browser is visiting.

The browser has already determined that and asked your server for it (which is why the `/rsvp` route is being hit in the first place).

---

Your options are:

- Change the link that the browser is posting to so it include the fragment ID in the first place
- Use the [P/G/R pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to redirect from the `post` route to a URL that the browser GETs and which includes the fragment id.
- Use *client-side* JS to scroll the page after enough of it has loaded

EJS isn't going to help you, except perhaps to conditionally include the client-side JS mentioned in the last of the above options.

Comment: Thanks for the response @quentin i thought EJS had an inbuilt context or function to that handles links